# django-registration URL cannot be resolved

Tags: django, django-registration

I am using django 1.5.1 with django-registration 1.0.

I am getting an error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password/reset/
Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done' with arguments '()' and     keyword arguments '{}' not found.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/password/reset/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

In my urls.py I have:

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls', namespace='re    gistration', app_name='registration')),
```

Anyone experience issues with this before?

Comment: Have you included `django.contrib.auth.urls` ? ([see it here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/urls.py)) `registration.backends.default.urls` doesn't supply login/logout/password management.

Comment: yep. Included it in a new line url(r'^account/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'),

Answer (score 0):

Just include the following lines and it should work:

    `url(r'accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),`

My urls.py:
```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'django_registration_demo.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls'))
```

)
```